# Example of Function in C

Tags: c, function, vector

I just start to study functions in C and this stopped me. I  want to write a function that searches for an element in a vector of `SIZE` elements. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int find(int vet[], int SIZE, int elem);

int main()
{
    int vett[SIZE] = {1, 59, 16, 0, 7, 32, 78, 90, 83, 14};
    int elem;

    printf ("Imput the element to find: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &elem);

    find(vett[SIZE], SIZE, elem);

    if (find == 1)
        printf ("\nI find the element!");
    else if (find == 2)
        printf ("\nI did not find the element!");

    return 0;
}

int find(int vett[], int SIZE, int elem)
{
    int i;
    int flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (vett[i] == elem)
            flag = 1;

    if (flag == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Why does Code::Blocks say to me:

```
|4|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant| 
||In function 'main':| |8|error: expected ']' before ';' token| 
|14|error: 'vett' undeclared (first use in this function)| 
|14|error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once| 
|14|error: for each function it appears in.)| 
|14|error: expected ']' before ';' token|
|14|error: expected ')' before ';' token| 
|16|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|

|18|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|
|24|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|
||=== Build finished: 8 errors, 2 warnings ===|
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SIZE as a constant and then you don't need to pass it to the function:

```
int find(int vet[], int elem);
```

If you want the function to be generic, and then define its prototype like this:

```
int find(int vet[], int size, int elem);
```

and call it like this:

```
find(vett, SIZE, elem);
```

and write it like this:

```
int find(int vett[], int size, int elem)
{
    int i;
    int flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (vett[i] == elem)
            flag = 1;

    if (flag == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

==EDIT==
regarding the question from the comment:
the `find` is a pointer to a function, it's not holding the return value. you can use it in one of the following ways:
-1-

```
int answer = find(vett[size], size, elem);

if (answer == 1)
    printf ("\nI find the element!");
else if (find == 2)
    printf ("\nI did not find the element!");
```

-2-

```
if (find(vett[size], size, elem) == 1)
    printf ("\nI find the element!");
else if (find == 2)
    printf ("\nI did not find the element!");
```

Comment: Thank You. I realize that SIZE is a constant so i don't need to pass it throught the function. But when i compile all, code::blocks says to me "warning: comparison between pointer and integer". Somethin wrong in "return 1 - return 2"??

Comment: for which line is the warning ?

Comment: if (find == 1)
        printf ("\nI find the element!");
    else if (find == 2)
        printf ("\nI did not find the element!");

Comment: As others are saying, you have problems in your code which are errors.  I suggest you fix the errors first and then tackle the warnings.  One problem is that 'find' is the name of a function and not a return value.  You should look up what a return value is through Google for a good explanation.  Basically, do something like 'int result = find (...)'.  When you return from find, what you return goes into 'result'.  You can't compare find (a function name) to a number.

Comment: Thank You, i solved putting "if(find(vett, elem) == 1" instead of "if (find == 1)" and all works now. TY guys for all support

Answer (score 6):

You are using the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) in places where you shouldn't; let me explain.

Your line

```
#define SIZE 10
```

tells the compiler that ALL occurences of the 4 letters "*SIZE*" are to be replaced by "*10*".

Which in your code will look like this:

```
int find(int vet[], int SIZE, int elem); // before preprocessor
int find(int vet[], int 10, int elem);   // after preprocessor -> syntax error
```

The second line is not valid in C.

What you should do is try to not use your preprocessor definitions as variable names.
For instance, what I do is: I name my preprocessor macros with CAPS (which you did) and *always* name my function variables with only *CamelCase* or *smallletters*.

**edit: my suggestion:**

```
int find(int vett[], int size, int elem);

int find(int vett[], int size, int elem)
{
    int i;
    int flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (vett[i] == elem)
            flag = 1;

    if (flag == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. So how i need to write the function declaration? Just without "SIZE" in his prototype?

Comment: Exactly; I would use '*size*', the same thing but in small letters. Be careful to also change the function **body**, where '*SIZE*' should be replaced by '*size*'.

Comment: Thanks! I need to declare "size" first in the "main" body?

Comment: No, in the main(), you call the function with *SIZE* as *size* argument for the find() function (re-read this slowly). This is a case where the macro is *used*.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing not the whole vector vett, but its SIZE-th element to the function find().